# Print n-th line after a matched line

Tags: perl

I have an input file having following contents

```
SCHEDULE "TEST"
 DESCRIPTION "Do Some stuff"
    MINUTE   "53"
    HOUR     "21"

SCHEDULE "DUMMY CHECK"
  DESCRIPTION "Do some stuff"

  Check something
    INTERVAL "10m"
    MINUTE   "50"
    HOUR     "21"
```

I need to match the 3rd line after the matched line SCHEDULE "DUMMY CHECK" which is INTERVAL "10m". (**Edit**: *and to get `10m` from it*.) I have written the below code for that purpose, however i'm not sure if this is the exact way of doing it, or do we have any simple other logics.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "input.txt";
my @data;
open (IN,"<","$file");
my $count = 0;
 while (<IN>) {
  $count = 1 if /SCHEDULE\s"(DUMMY\sCHECK)".*/;
    if ($count >= 1 and $count <= 6) {
    @data = $_;
    print @data;
    $count++;  
    }

 }
```

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1216577).

Comment: Do you really need to count the line after a pattern? It's not so reliable. (For example, the `INTERVAL` line  _is not_ the 3rd line below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `flip-flop` operator. This lets you operate only on the SCHEDULE "DUMMY CHECK" sections. From there, it doesn't matter what line you're on and you can just capture the INTERVAL field.

```
use v5.10;

open (IN,"<","$ARGV[0]");

while (<IN>) {
    if (/^SCHEDULE "DUMMY CHECK"/ .. eof) {
        say "interval: $1" if /INTERVAL (.*)/
    }
}
```

note that I am using `eof` as the flip-flop terminator. you can "flop" on another regular expression (maybe `/^SCHEDULE/`) if there is more to the data file.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** in comments: get data on `INTERVAL` line if it is the 4th line after `DUMMY` line

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift @ARGV  or usage();

open my $fh_in, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my $offset = 4;

my $anchor;
while (<$fh_in>) { 
    $anchor = $.  if /SCHEDULE\s"DUMMY\sCHECK"/;
    if ($anchor and $. == $anchor+$offset and /^\s*INTERVAL\s*"(.*?)"/) {
        #print;                 # the whole line
        say "interval is: $1";  # captured data on the line
    }
}

sub usage {
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 filename";
    exit;
}
```

The [`$.` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.) has the current line number from the last accessed filehandle.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, my intention is to get the last line which is INTERVAL "10m" and get the value 10m store in to a variable. How can i do that here.

Comment: @user3834663  Alright, that's what my comment (under the question) was about: do you need the 4th line after the `DUMMY CHECK`, or the line with `INTERVAL`?  Or the `INTERVAL` line if it is the 4th line? Or if it is between the 1st and 6th lines after `DUMMY`?  Please consider carefully what the most suitable requirement is.  (Since there aren't other answers yet it'd be probably good to then update the question as well.)

Comment: @user3834663  I can simply add a line to extract data after `INTERVAL` but it isn't good to search for the 4th line and then use a particular text pattern on it. That should be wrapped together in a more robust test.

Comment: Yes i need the interval comes after the DUMMY CHECK.

Comment: @user3834663  "yes" on which of options I listed?  That the line has `INTERVAL` and that it is the fourth line after the `DUMMY` line?

Comment: $data =~ m/\s+INTERVAL\s\"(.*)\".*/i;
$int = $1;
print "interval is = $int\n";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173097/discussion-between-user3834663-and-zdim).

Comment: @user3834663  See the last update (extract data from within quotes now).  Thank you for the attribution